# react-native-snap-carousel have bugs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I can't use react-native-snap-carousel.

> react-native-snap-carouselD:/web/ReactNativeCarouselTutorial/node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/pagination/PaginationDot.js
> Attempted import error: 'ViewPropTypes' is not exported from
> 'react-native-web/dist/index'.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
Module.D:\web\ReactNativeCarouselTutorial\node_modules\react-native-snap- 
carousel\src\carousel\Carousel.js
D:/web/ReactNativeCarouselTutorial/node_modules/react-native-snap- 
carousel/src/carousel/Carousel.js:46
43 | autoplayDelay: PropTypes.number, 
44 | autoplayInterval: PropTypes.number,
45 | callbackOffsetMargin: PropTypes.number,
> 46 | containerCustomStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,
| ^  47 | contentContainerCustomStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,
48 | enableMomentum: PropTypes.bool,
49 | enableSnap: PropTypes.bool,
```

Comment: Could you please share the part of code where you are importing `ViewPropTypes `?

Comment: import { Animated, Easing, FlatList, I18nManager, Platform, ScrollView, View, ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';                                                                                                                                                                 
containerCustomStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,
        contentContainerCustomStyle: ViewPropTypes ? ViewPropTypes.style : View.propTypes.style,

Comment: Writes that the error is not in my code, the error is react-native-snap-carousel in npm

Comment: It seems a problem who came out after the version `0.12.x`, this work around seems work for many https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1537#issuecomment-619969653, it say to add `export const ViewPropTypes = { style: null };` into `/../node_modules/react-native-web/dist/index.js`